# Spring Security and OPTIONS, *NO* CORS

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-web

That's NOT "yet another question on CORS support in Spring Security".

I am perfectly aware that the exist an elegant solution - more than one, actually - of using a Spring-provided CorsFilter to make preflight requests bypass authentication filter chain. For one, there is CorsConfigurationSource, also there is CorsRegistry. Of course I prefer those solutions, as being integrated into Spring Security, unlike writing my own filter and second-guessing if I'm correctly handling all aspects of CORS interactions.

Problem is, CorsFilter is doing exactly what the name suggests, it provides special handling for CORS preflight requests. But if we open HTTP 1.1 method specifications, we can see that, for instance, OPTIONS method is described without any reference to CORS at all! So, even though it's commonly used by browsers, no one says it cannot be used by any sort of client, or by JavaScript code running in a browser *but* from the same domain (in this case I believe the browser will not force CORS headers on the outgoing request). I even found some mentions on the internet of OPTIONS being used for "liveness" checks ("pinging" the server).

I also know that Spring will successfully serve OPTIONS request (not just cross-origin but any) if allowed to.

Now my question is: what is the *recommended* (supposed?) way to let non-crossdomain OPTIONS request bypass authentication?

P.S. In case you wonder how CorsFilter is not able to do that: it checks for presence of CORS mandatory request headers like "Origin". Which are not mandatory if it's not a cross-domain request.

Comment: As one solution, I suppose I can use some request matcher with some new security chain. But it's not as easy as it sounds: if we just let through all OPTIONS requests, there may be some CORS-specific processing in Spring which is executed by CorsFilter, and if the request is actually CORS, we don't want to skip that processing as well. But maybe it's the way to go. Or maybe there is another supposed solution, like there is one for CORS?

Comment: ... regarding my last comment, an example of such processing is DefaultCorsProcessor.handleInternal and other methods, which perform all kinds of validations and set the necessary response headers. Speaking of which, since this processor is not activated for non-CORS OPTIONS requests, I am not sure what code serves the latter. It's some other code and it sets another set of headers ("Allow" for instance).